# How to disable space change by the mouse moving to the screen edge

Tags: high-sierra, mouse, mission-control

When I drag a window with the mouse to a screen edge and keep it there for
half a second or so my Mac switches to the next/previous space.

This behaviour happens on High Sierra and seems to be part of the OS's *Mission Control* feature.

How can I disable this gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Spaces: howto disable Switch by dragging - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2372497?login=true)

In the Terminal, execute

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay 15 && killall Dock
```

will set the delay when dragging to screen edge to another desktop to too high that macOS would not do anything.
Tried it myself and works for me.